# Simple explanation of "Solve a System of Equations" in R

Tags: r

I am a student of political science, who has just starting working with R. Amongst others, i use this program to do bayesian statistics. And it is in regards to this, i have a question:

Can some explain (somewhat simple) what the command `solve(t(x)%*%x)` do?

**Given example:**

```
s<-seq(1,5)
x<-cbind(1,s)
```

**Output of solve(t(x)%*%x):**

```
          s
   1.1 -0.3
s -0.3  0.1
```

I know what `t(x)%*%x` does, but i can't figure out, what the solve-command does. 
This might be very simple, but my knowledge of math and programming is quite limited.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

From the description of ?solve:
"This generic function solves the equation a %*% x = b for x, where b can be either a vector or a matrix." 
And: "If missing, b is taken to be an identity matrix and solve will return the inverse of a."

In your case b is missing.

```
A <- t(x)%*%x
```

So A is

```
      s
   5 15
s 15 55
```

Now

```
B <- solve(A)
```

gives you the inverse of A. Try it out:

`A %*% B` gives

```
    s
  1 0
s 0 1
```

which is the identity.